# Clickatell SMS Troublshooting

Tags: civisms

I'm runnning the bitnami image on Google cloud (5.0.1), trying to get sms reminders working.

Provider Account is set up and tested, extension installed and configured, but when I send a test sms it is reported as delivered by Civi, but it's not, and nothing appears in the providers reporting either, so I assume there has been no actual communication with the gateway.

How can I troubleshoot this? Does the extension work with 5.1?

Comment: Ah, extensions weren't the problem, the problem was there were no recipients reported in the test group I was using, although there are quite a lot of contacts with telephone numbers in the group. I assume I must have to prepare the contacts in a different way to pick up their numbers?

Comment: Ok, number has to be labelled mobile, I didn't see that in the documentation. So I have contacts in the sms group now but still no sucessful sms mailings using either Twilio or Clikatel. Now going to try again with debugging turned on

Comment: I'm still no further along, I'm going to assume Clickatell is broke, there are no errors reported, but Clickatell reports no interaction. I have to purchase a "number" from Twilio before I can test it properly (they used to give away free test numbers apparently) but I'm loathe to stump up cash unless I know it will work, unless anyone has any other suggestions?

Comment: Sean - have you raised this on the Clickatell extension issues? We've done some work recently to allow old and new keys to work, would be good to have a look at why yours isn't working. https://github.com/veda-consulting/org.civicrm.sms.clickatell/issues

Comment: Thanks Parvez, I did look at the issues list originally, thought the issue might be the characters in the API key [(#15)](https://github.com/veda-consulting/org.civicrm.sms.clickatell/issues/15), but if that was the problem, I'd see something in the logs wouldn't I, not successful delivery reported

Answer (score 2):

Aha, nothing wrong with either extension, after some time I finally noticed the timezone mismatch with the server